# Get opposite match with preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, regex

I want to convert an entire text string to uppercase except text written within angled brackets.

I also want to remove the surrending brackets.

I have made the following code, but it does the opposite:

```
    $text='this PART should be CONVERTED to uppercase [This PART should not BE changed] this part should also be CONVERTED to uppercase [THIS part should also not be CHANGED] etc..';      

    $text = preg_replace_callback(
        "(\[(.*?)\])is",
        function($m) {

            return strtoupper($m[1]);
        },
        $text);
    echo $text;
```

Comment: Check what is in `$m` using `var_dump($m);`, you take `$m[1]` -> the match for the first subpattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the PCRE verbs `SKIP` and `FAIL` to skip those matches. You can read more about these here, http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html.

```
$text='this PART should be CONVERTED to uppercase [This PART should not BE changed] this part should also be CONVERTED to uppercase [THIS part should also not be CHANGED] etc..';      
$text = preg_replace_callback(
        "/\[(.*?)\](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\w+/is",
        function($m) {
            return strtoupper($m[0]);
        },
        $text);
echo $text;
```

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/nwG2wW/4/
PHP Demo: https://3v4l.org/rkFUGd

Comment: Looks great :) Can you tell me how to delete the brackets also?

Comment: You can't delete the brackets with this approach. This is the opposite of your match, e.g. if it matches ignore it, otherwise select the content and capitalize it. You could do `str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', $text)` after the call; https://3v4l.org/1Yek0, that assumes you just want all brackets removed, that doesn't check that are balanced.

Answer (score 0):

[`[^][]++(?=\[|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/cud9c3/1)

```
Match a single character not present in the list below [^][]++
++ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, without giving back (possessive)
][ matches a single character in the list ][ (case sensitive)
Positive Lookahead (?=\[|$)
Assert that the Regex below matches
1st Alternative \[
\[ matches the character [ literally (case sensitive)
2nd Alternative $
$ asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)
```